# Middleware Called before any request in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am developing a NodeJS Api and having some issues with middlewares.
routes are accessible to user based on their roles and a role could be Admin or superAdmin.
My permission middleware looks like this:

```
permission.js

// middleware for doing role-based permissions
const { getRoleName } = require('../../constants/roles');
module.exports = function permit(...allowed) {
    const isAllowed = role => allowed.indexOf(role) > -1;
    console.log(isAllowed)
    // return a middleware
    return (req, res, next) => {
        //findRole Name

        if (req.user && isAllowed(getRoleName[req.user.role]))
            next(); // role is allowed, so continue on the next middleware
        else {
            res.error({ code: 403, message: 'Forbidden', errors: ['Permission Denied'] }); // user is forbidden
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an authentication middleware which attaches logged in user to `req.user`.
I am using this permission-based middleware into my routes Like this.

```
records.js
const permit = require("../middlewares/permissions/permission"); 
router.get("/", permit("superAdmin"), getAllRecords);
router.get("/route1", permit("admin"), getRouteOneRecords);
router.get("/route2", permit("admin","superAdmin"), getRouteTwoRecords);
```

Now the problem is when my app runs all the roles are printing without making any request,
**console.log(isAllowed)**, this line in permission.js is printing the roles without any request made to any of the routes.

I wonder why this is happening, even before making a request to the route.

Answer (score 1):

just because in each route you are executing the permit() method, inside of that you are executing this block before return your middleware function:

```
const isAllowed = role => allowed.indexOf(role) > -1;
    console.log(isAllowed)
    // return a middleware
```

But for sure that the content for this function `return (req, res, next) => {` are gonna be executed as the middleware purpose when you execute the route.

Comment: but it should be fired only after I pass a request to that route. right ?

Comment: yes, only the callback function inside your middleware